# SQL Server Error 14013 - This database is not enabled for publication

Tags: sql-server, errors, error-handling

I am trying to configure a database publication with T-SQL.

```
use master
exec sp_replicationdboption 
    @dbname='anun', 
    @optname=N'publish',
    @value = N'true';
```

It runs successfully and I see this if I run the second time

> The replication option 'publish' of database 'anun' has already been set to true.
>
> Msg 14013, Level 16, State 1, Procedure
>   sys.sp_MSrepl_addlogreader_agent
>   **This database is not enabled for publication**.

I can't understand why it brings this error if I have already set replication option `True` for this db. Is there other replication option that I should also enable?

Comment: Does this solve your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407937/how-to-configure-replication-this-dasp_replicationdboptiontabase-is-not-enabled-for-publication   . Use anun instead of use master in your script.